# Filling up one dropdown with same value of the other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Currently I have 2 dropdown boxes with the same options. These options are all filled from the backend. Now I want it so that whenever I choose 1 option in the dropdown box, the other dropdown also automatically chooses the same value and this works both ways. The following is my dropdown box code:

```
        <select name="lead_status" id="leadstatus" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <?php foreach($leadstatus as $key => $status): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>" <?php echo $key==$lead->lead_status?'selected="selected"':'' ?>><?php echo $status; ?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <select name="lead_status" id="leadstatus2" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <?php foreach($leadstatus as $key => $status): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>" <?php echo $key==$lead->lead_status?'selected="selected"':'' ?>><?php echo $status; ?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
```

I've tried creating a function for onclick where it creates a check saying:

```
if (document.getElementById('leadstatus').value == '1')
  document.getElementById("leadstatus2").value = '1';
```

But this wont work since I have a lot of data in the dropdown lists and it is dynamic.

Comment: What is the purpose of having two dropdowns which exactly mirror each other? I can't work out what you're trying to achieve with that

Comment: 1 of the dropdown goes to an agent and 1 goes to a manager. The agent has limited access, but the manager will have full access

Comment: That makes no sense as far as I can see. All you can do from your page is submit data to the server. So, submit the data once, and then use some code on the server to save it where the relevant people can see it - which probably still involves only saving it in one place, but just having code to stop the limited user from viewing data they shouldn't. You didn't give details but it sounds like maybe you're planning to save the data twice in two different places? That's a design flaw. This question smells like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set the second dropdown's `selectedIndex` property to that of the first dropdown:

```js
let box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
let box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
box1.addEventListener("change", () => {
  box2.selectedIndex = box1.selectedIndex;
});
box2.addEventListener("change", () => {
  box1.selectedIndex = box2.selectedIndex;
});
```

```html
<select id="box1">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
<select id="box2">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This only works in one direction I think. Question asks for it to be bidirectional

Comment: I edited, now it works both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question mentions...
**...the other dropdown also automatically chooses the same value and this works both ways...**

Try the following, ..

```
const leadStatusList = document.getElementById('leadstatus');
const leadStatus2List = document.getElementById('leadstatus2');

const setDropdownValue = (event) => {
  leadStatusList.value = event.target.value;
  leadStatus2List.value = event.target.value;
}

leadStatusList.onchange = setDropdownValue;
leadStatus2List.onchange = setDropdownValue;
```